# How to formulate an exponential form for Fourier Series function?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

Let $f:[0, 2\pi] \to  \mathbb{R}$ continuous function. Show that the Fourier series exponential form is equal to
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}c_ne^{inx}
\end{align}
for a specific choice of $c_n$.

Now my attempt was basically taking the known methodology:
\begin{align}
f(x) = a_0 + \sum a_n \cos \left( nx \dfrac{\pi}{L} \right) +  \sum b_n \sin \left( nx \dfrac{\pi}{L} \right)
\end{align}
and also
\begin{align}
&a_0 = \dfrac{1}{2L} \int_{-L}^{L}f(x) dx\\
&a_n = \dfrac{1}{L} \int_{-L}^{L}f(x)\cos \left( nx \dfrac{\pi}{L} \right) dx\\
&b_n = \dfrac{1}{L} \int_{-L}^{L}f(x)\sin \left( nx \dfrac{\pi}{L} \right) dx
\end{align}
and I am 100% sure we must use the identity $e^{ix} = \cos x+ i \sin x$ but I am not really  sure how to piece this together.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $c_{0} = a_{0}$ and solve the system

$c_{n}e^{inx}+c_{-n}e^{-inx} = a_{n}\cos\left(nx\right) +  b_{n}\sin\left(nx\right)$

In the end you will get

$$
c_{n} = \frac{1}{2L}\int_{-L}^{L}f\left(x\right)e^{-inx}dx
$$

Comment: Many thanks. I did that on the closed segment $[0, 2\pi]$ but it's still okay.